# Function Syntax not compiling - VHDL

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I'm a total beginner to VHDL and I've no freaking idea why I'm getting errors. If I remove the function everything compiles just right, but when I put it back I get the following errors:

Syntax error near "function".

Syntax error near "begin".

Syntax error near "when".

Syntax error near "when".

And you get the idea.

Here's the god forsaken function:

```
    function decod ( x : in integer range 0 to 9)
return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is 
variable temp : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
    begin
    case x is
        when 0 => temp <= "0000001"; -- 0
        when 1 => temp <= "1001111"; -- 1
        when 2 => temp <= "0010010"; -- 2
        when 3 => temp <= "0000110"; -- 3 
        when 4 => temp <= "1001100"; -- 4
        when 5 => temp <= "0100100"; -- 5
        when 6 => temp <= "0100000"; -- 6
        when 7 => temp <= "0001111"; -- 7
        when 8 => temp <= "0000000"; -- 8 
        when 9 => temp <= "0000100"; -- 9 
    end case;
    return temp;
end decod;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kevin's answer that you should remove the mode in on the variable declaration you are using the wrong assignment type `temp <=` should be `temp :=`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    function decod ( x : in integer range 0 to 9)
return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is 
variable temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
    begin
    case x is
        when 0 => temp := "0000001"; -- 0
        when 1 => temp := "1001111"; -- 1
        when 2 => temp := "0010010"; -- 2
        when 3 => temp := "0000110"; -- 3 
        when 4 => temp := "1001100"; -- 4
        when 5 => temp := "0100100"; -- 5
        when 6 => temp := "0100000"; -- 6
        when 7 => temp := "0001111"; -- 7
        when 8 => temp := "0000000"; -- 8 
        when 9 => temp := "0000100"; -- 9 
    end case;
    return temp;
end decod;
begin
end architecture;
```

This analyzes and elaborates.

Note the function is declared by it's subprogram body in the architecture declarative region.

A subprogram body isn't allowed in a package declaration, the function's body would be found in the corresponding package  package body:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


package fum is
    function decod ( x : in integer range 0 to 9) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
end package fum;

package body fum is

    function decod ( x : in integer range 0 to 9) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is 
        variable temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
    begin
        case x is
            when 0 => temp := "0000001"; -- 0
            when 1 => temp := "1001111"; -- 1
            when 2 => temp := "0010010"; -- 2
            when 3 => temp := "0000110"; -- 3 
            when 4 => temp := "1001100"; -- 4
            when 5 => temp := "0100100"; -- 5
            when 6 => temp := "0100000"; -- 6
            when 7 => temp := "0001111"; -- 7
            when 8 => temp := "0000000"; -- 8 
            when 9 => temp := "0000100"; -- 9 
        end case;
        return temp;
    end decod;
end package body;
```

It can be useful to those providing answers to see the actual error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "in" keyword from the variable declaration. It is also not necessary to specify "in" on the function parameter list because functions only take "in" parameters. You only need to specify direction on ports and procedures.

Comment: Get rid of the range on integer. If you want it constrained (needed for synthesis) create an integer subtype outside the function or switch to an `unsigned` type.